# ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! On latex studio

Tags: errors, packages

I faced the following message when I run my latex studio file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.9.26)  14 NOV 2023 13:51
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Project.tex
(./Project.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count194
\leftroot@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count196
\DOTSCASE@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count199
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count266
\dspbrk@lvl=\count267
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count268
\column@=\count269
\maxfields@=\count270
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks22
\thm@bodyfont=\toks23
\thm@headfont=\toks24
\thm@notefont=\toks25
\thm@headpunct=\toks26
\thm@preskip=\skip53
\thm@postskip=\skip54
\thm@headsep=\skip55
\dth@everypar=\toks27
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))

! LaTeX Error: File `thmtools.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.5 \usepackage
               {graphicx}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1507 strings out of 476888
 18278 string characters out of 5809173
 1917785 words of memory out of 5000000
 22866 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,0n,65p,224b,36s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: there is a package missing: ``! LaTeX Error: File `thmtools.sty' not found``. Either install it or remove it from your document.

Comment: thankyou so much, It is run successfully :)